# Customize DevExpress scheduler control timeline view header

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, scheduler

How to customize devexpress scheduler control timeline view header.
The date of default header is "Tuesday, July 23 2013 - Sunday, July 28 2013". I need to make header just  like this "2013.07.23-2013.07.28".
Sorry for my bad Englsih.
Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task by customizing the [TimeScale.DisplayFormat](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraSchedulerTimeScale_DisplayFormattopic) property of the [TimeScaleWeek](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXtraSchedulerTimeScaleWeektopic) scale:

```
var timeScaleWeek = new DevExpress.XtraScheduler.TimeScaleWeek();
timeScaleWeek.DisplayFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd";
schedulerControl1.Views.TimelineView.Scales.Add(timeScaleWeek);
```

Comment: Default timescale and new timescale are both displayed.How to remove default one?

Comment: @DavaahuuJamsran My code is only demonstration of usage context... You can only change the DiaplayFormat property of the default scale without adding new one.